# Unity random clone coordinate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to generate the x coordinate of the clone with a random unique number but I'm getting an error. Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

```
void Start(){
            for (int j = 0; j < 17; j++)
        {
            int r =Random.Range(-1,2);
            Debug.Log("random"+r);

            a = a + 5;
                var abc = Instantiate(toplar[3], new Vector3(numbers[0], 0.4f, a), Quaternion.identity);
                abc.transform.parent = go.transform;
                var abc2 = Instantiate(toplar[4], new Vector3(numbers[1], 0.4f, a), Quaternion.identity);
                abc2.transform.parent = go.transform;
                var abc3 = Instantiate(toplar[5], new Vector3(numbers[2], 0.4f, a), Quaternion.identity);
                abc3.transform.parent = go.transform;
            //Debug.Log("oluştu");
        }}

public int  NewNumber()
{
        int a = Random.Range(-1, 2);
        if (!numbers.Contains(a))
        {
            numbers.Add(a);
        }
        return a;
}
```

Comment: Can't be negative : Random.Range(-1, 2);

Comment: i did Random.Range(2, 5); again error

Answer (score 0):

You used numbers[x], but do you generate numbers in NewNumber()?
And if you used 'public int New Number()' 3 times - there is a chance that a random value will occur twice and numbers.Count == 2 (or 1). You need pre-generate numbers in list "numbers" before used.

Comment: thanks but how can I do that?

Comment: Just call NewNumber() while numbers.count < 3 (or more, if you need more numbers)